# Xorg crashed and all apps killed after waking up from suspend?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, crash

My computer wakes up from suspend.  I have to log-in twice to get to the desktop, just to find that everything is closed.
Some processes are still visible in the Monitor though.

I have a crash report with:

```
ExecutablePath
/usr/bin/Xorg
Package
xserver-xorg-core 2:1.15.1-0ubntu2.1
Problem Type
Crash
Title
Xorg crashed with SIGABRT
proc.driver.nvidia.gpus.0
Error: Errno 21 is a directory /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0
```

and so on....

Is the Nvidia binary driver giving the problems again? Any way around it?
It's terrible because you just don't know if you will find your work killed or it will be fine (doesn't happen every time but like 1 out of 10)

Comment: it would probably help if you pasted more of your log file on pastebin.ubuntu.com and posted the URL of your paste.

Comment: i'll do that next time it happens

Comment: Quite a few days have passed since this post was written. HOwever, the issue seems to have remained a couple of distro upgrades ... I'm running 16.04 on a DELL Precision 5510 and experience exactly the same behaviour. Have any viable solutions been found in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

I had the error

```
Xorg crashed with signal 7
Error: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0'
```

I found this was [Bug #1763645 "Xorg crashed with signal 7"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/1763645), a duplicate of [Bug #1760450 "[nvidia] Xorg crashed with signal 7 in _dl_fixup() from _dl_runtime_resolve_xsavec() called from nvidia_drv.so"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1760450).

What worked for me (driver 390) was in the comments:

Add `scsi_mod.scan=sync` to `/etc/default/grub` like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="scsi_mod.scan=sync"
```

No resuming from suspend crashes yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have these problems, and then I simply accepted that it was less problematic to simply shut down my laptop instead of using features like sleep or suspend.  I think these features are more popular with Windows users because it boots up in what, a day and a half?  Then Windows the user grief when all they want to do is shut down and Windows insists on installing updates instead.  In my experience Ubuntu shuts down in 5-10 seconds on average, and boots nearly as fast.

As for your NVIDIA driver complaints, I agree.  I installed drivers on this very installation when I was using an HP laptop, and now that I've moved onto a desktop WITH THE SAME INSTALLATION, I could not wait to purge all the NVIDIA drivers which I only recently accomplished.  My installation runs a lot better without them, but I'm not sure I'd blame the NVIDIA drivers for the suspend problems.

Comment: yeah the thing is that i have a lot of windows configured in certain way, so it saves a lot of time to suspend instead of setting them up every time.
With 13.10 and those drivers, suspend wasn't working at all actually, so we have a progress....kinda :)